# JPanel does not appear correctly while extending JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

This is my homework.

My directions:
Class GuessGame: This class contains the main function which creates a JFrame object, sets up the JFrame’s size, visibility and exit.

Class GuessGameFrame: GuessGameFrame class extends JFrame.  So the GuessGameFrame class has all variables and methods defined in class JFrame.

I am not 100% sure what my problem is but I believe the JPanel is not working correctly

Any help would greatly be appreciated, if I left out anything important please let me know and I can add more detail.

main class:

```
public class GuessGame {

             public static void main(String[] args){
                  GuessGameFrame localGuessGameFrame = new GuessGameFrame();
                  localGuessGameFrame.setVisible(true); //set visible
                  localGuessGameFrame.setSize(380,175); // set size 380 width 175 height
                  localGuessGameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(localGuessGameFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // needed to enable the red X button to close the program
             }
}
```

extended class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GuessGameFrame extends JFrame
    {

    private int lastDistance; // distance between last guess and number
    private Color background; // background color of application

    private JFrame f;
    static JPanel p;
    private JButton b1;
    private JLabel l1;
    private JLabel l2;
    JTextField t1 = new JTextField(8);
    private JLabel l3;

    //declare constructor
    public GuessGameFrame()
    {
    //create our JFrame
    f = new JFrame("Guessing game");

    //create our panel
        p = new JPanel();
        p.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA); // background color is magenta

        //create our labels
        l1 = new JLabel("I have a number between 1 and 1000.");
        l2 = new JLabel("Can you guess my number? Enter your first Guess:.");
        l3 = new JLabel("Guess result appears here.");
        //create our button
        b1 = new JButton("New Game");

        //add button and label to panel
        p.add(l1); // Adds label 1
        p.add(l2); // adds label 2
        p.add(t1); // adds textfield 1
        p.add(l3); // adds label 3
        p.add(b1); // adds button 1

        //add panel to JFrame
        f.add(p);
    }
}
```

Screenshot of the output window when executed:
[image]

I expect it to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need remove `JFrame f` in `GuessGameFrame` class because `GuessGameFrame` is already a `JFrame`:

And update your code:

`f = new JFrame("Guessing game");` to `this.setTitle("Guessing game");`

`f.add(p);` to `this.getContentPane().add(p);`

Comment: This worked!!! Could you explain why it worked, maybe focusing on the 'this' bit.

Comment: Because in your code, GuessGameFrame is a JFrame itself and it contains another JFrame f. You init UI for JFrame f (not GuessGameFrame) and in the main class you call localGuessGameFrame.setVisible(true), so it will not work

Comment: @Jerry06: both `this` and `getContentPane()` are redundant, but they make it clear that you are invoking the methods of an instance of `GuessGameFrame`.